# Render Difference vs. Mobile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

The table, created by Tom, renders a bit awkward on my Nexus 4.

- On my desktop it renders OK: [Answer on Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50730/29140)

---

On my phone:

[image]

Model: Nexus 4, OS:4.3, Browser: Chrome Beta
OS: Win7, Chrome (stable, latest)

Comment: Note - I used [AsciiFlow] ( http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html?m=1). Probably should have used the ascii version rather than the Unicode version. Sorry - will change it.

Comment: Jacob doesn't appear to be using the android app, @Sklivvz (where the answer does appear to render correctly) - for that matter, he doesn't appear to be using the mobile view either (where I can confirm this answer renders appropriately as well). Marking this as status-bydesign; retag if you happen to have a fix in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are always some number of rendering inconsistencies between the mobile and desktop versions of Chrome, even if you're *not* using any beta versions.

That's why we have a mobile version of the site, accessible via the "mobile" link in the footer - I can confirm that the table (while indeed poorly-rendered in the full site on mobile Chrome) appears normally in the mobile view.

I recommend using the mobile view under normal circumstances, resorting to the full page only when something is inaccessible or [broken](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/its-impossible-to-flag-duplicate-on-a-mobile) in the normal view.